# Последующее сохранение вписанного значения в input с тегом form

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы вписанный текст string в input сохранялся после обновления страницы.

Какие варианты есть решения данной задачи?

Сам PUG-код строки input:

```
tab(title="biography")
            .character-tab(*tabContent)
                input.form-control#biography(
                                [(ngModel)]="deda.biography" placeholder="example: Im from ...)
```

Comment: Local Storage, Cookies, сервер... Pug здесь ни при чём.

Answer (score 0):

Через js можно значение input записать в url как переменную, а затем, после обновления, присвоить это значение input'у.
Но все же, при возможности, думаю лучше обработать это на сервере и при необходимости заполнить input значением, полученным из input от клиента.